# Geting C API function help from Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

I have VS 2015. In previous versions I was able to press F1 on a C function and get help. But now it always gives C++ help. For example, if I press F1 on "select" I get help for Select:

```
public:
static Selection^ Select(
    EditingContext^ context, 
    ModelItem^ itemToSelect
)
```

I then have to use MSDN via IE to get my help,.

I have used Help->Add and Remove Help Content but can only find C++. I have checked all over the internet and have not found any solution to this.

Is there something else I need to do?